# reading json url file returns blank screen on my Android phone

Tags: android, json, parsing, rest

this is my first post on Stackoverflow and I am trying to learn Android. I need to read a json file from within an android application.

I ran the following code on my phone and it doesn't display anything on my phone, I just get a blank screen.

I know there are ways to use Java libraries to parse json but that's is NOT what I am looking for. I would like to accomplish reading this json using ONLY tools provided by Android. Here's my json

I am using Android 4.0.3
Here's my json file data:

```
{
    "offers": [
        {
                "id": "1",
                "type":"xyz",
                "description":"blah blah",
                "url":"http://www.example.com/"
        },
        {
                "id": "1",
                "type":"xyz",
                "description":"some description",
                "url":"http://www.example.com/"
        },
        {
                "id": "1",
                "type":"xyz",
                "description":"some description",
                "url":"http://www.example.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
package com.pega.parsejson;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView jsonWrapper;
    HttpClient httpClient;
    JSONObject json;


    final static String offersUrl="http://somewebsite.com/offers.json";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        jsonWrapper=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonWrap);
        httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        new Read().execute("description");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public JSONObject jsonOffers() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        //StringBuilder url=new StringBuilder(offersUrl);

        HttpGet get=new HttpGet(offersUrl);
        HttpResponse res=httpClient.execute(get);
        int status=res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(status==200){
            HttpEntity e=res.getEntity();
            String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray timeline=new JSONArray("offers");
            JSONObject jsonOffer=timeline.getJSONObject(0); //returns most recent offer
            return jsonOffer;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                json=jsonOffers();
                return (String) json.get("description"); //returns string w/ parameter passed in as "description"
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            jsonWrapper.setText(result);
        }

    }

}
```

I am also using the INTERNET PERMISSIONS:

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pega.parsejson"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pega.parsejson.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here's my textview right below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jsonWrap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my logcat:

```
[2013-08-07 23:35:41 - parseJson] ------------------------------
[2013-08-07 23:35:41 - parseJson] Android Launch!
[2013-08-07 23:35:41 - parseJson] adb is running normally.
[2013-08-07 23:35:41 - parseJson] Performing com.pega.parsejson.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-08-07 23:35:42 - parseJson] Uploading parseJson.apk onto device 'HT25EHX00690'
[2013-08-07 23:35:42 - parseJson] Installing parseJson.apk...
[2013-08-07 23:35:45 - parseJson] Success!
[2013-08-07 23:35:45 - parseJson] Starting activity com.pega.parsejson.MainActivity on device HT25EHX00690
[2013-08-07 23:35:46 - parseJson] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.pega.parsejson/.MainActivity }
```

Please note I do NOT want to use any json libraries to parse my json, I strictly would like to use ONLY android to parse the json. I just don't get why my mainActivity.java doesn't display anything on phone.

Apologize for the length of my post, really need help on this for a time sensitive project and YES, I have already read other similar questions on Stackoverflow and none seem to answer this question.

Could anybody please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: So many questions... have you verified that you're reading & parsing the JSON correctly?  If not.. prune code down to something you can test & verify independently (should be able to parse & verify with a simple standalone java program - unit tests!!!).  If that's not the issue.. then perhaps your question is about displaying on android.. again prune (remove JSON parsing) and get that working.  Until you can *clarify* and *simplify* this question to a core issue, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Not to discourage you - it was a great start to a first question!  Just trying to help you help us help you... errr.. something like that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error lies in the code:

```
HttpEntity e=res.getEntity();
String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);
JSONArray timeline=new JSONArray("offers");
JSONObject jsonOffer=timeline.getJSONObject(0); //returns most recent offer
return jsonOffer;
```

The reason is that you are creating a NEW JSONArray instead of using the array from the JSON you receive.

Instead, you should parse the JSON you receive, using the built-in JSONObject and then select the array.  Assuming `data` holds the JSON text, you could do something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray timeline = json.getJSONArray("offers");
return timeline.getJSONObject(0); // return most recent offer
```

Comment: I just ran the following on my phone, no success. I added the <user-Internet permisison> still nothing :( if(status==200){
   HttpEntity e=res.getEntity();
   String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
   JSONArray timeline = json.getJSONArray("offers");
   return timeline.getJSONObject(0); // return most recent offer
  }

Comment: Add a breakpoint or log message and make sure the code is running as you think it is.  Ensure that `data` contains the JSON string from the web. As others have mentioned, you need to isolate where the area is as there are many parts to your app.  Ensure each one works in order.

Comment: I just debugged it and it looks like the very last line, return timeline.getJSONObject(0), throws an error during evaluation. I "watched" variables like "data" in debug mode and was happy to see that the "data" variable actually stored the whole json file. However, the last line where it retuns the json obj is throwing an evaluation error.

Comment: Okay, great.  So now what was the error?  And did you "watch" the `json` and `timeline` variables to ensure they parse the `JSONObject` correctly and then retrieve the `JSONArray` correctly?

Comment: Thanks, it throws a JSONException: index 3 out of range; here's the logcat link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szv9rv8yx18fgkd/jsonError.PNG; I dont think im out of bounds with the json array, so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: As soon as I "jump over" in eclipse debug mode, it jumps from "JSONObject js= timeline.getJSONObject(0);
   return js;" to "return null"; any clue why? Thanks btw for your time. Here's logcat trace: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szv9rv8yx18fgkd/jsonError.PNG; thanks

Comment: Better news, I can now see the string that I want when I "watch" and hover over it in debug mode but when I run the whole program it still shows up blank on my phone. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using index 3?  The code is using index 0 above.  If you are doing something different and the JSON is as shown above, don't forget that the index is 0-based, meaning to access the third item you should use index [2].  Index [3] would be out of range (and thus cause an exception).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if(status==200){
            HttpEntity e=res.getEntity();
            String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);

            JSONObject jObj;
            JSONArray data = null;
            JSONObject jsonOffer;

            jObj = new JSONObject(data);
            data = jObj.getJSONArray("offers");
            jsonOffer=data.getJSONObject(0);
            return jsonOffer;
    }
```

get values like

```
String id = jsonOffer.getString("id");
```

we have created json Object for your json. then we have got the array which is under "Offers" key. so we have data as an array. then we have got the first object of array in jsonoffer object. so we have data in jsonoffer and we can retrieve value by getString(keyName).

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Hey Armaan, I tried this but still didn't get anything on my screen. Just a blank screen. Is there a specific place in my code where I should put that?

Comment: Have you checked that jsonOffer have value when it returns??

Comment: sorry but solution you provided still did not work. Any way you could maybe elaborate on your code? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following,

```
public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected JSONObjectdoInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                json=jsonOffers();
                return  json;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

 try {
            JSONArray offers=result.getJSONArray("offers");
            for(int i=0;i<offers.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj1=offers.getJSONObject(0);
                String desc1=obj1.getString("description");

                JSONObject obj2=offers.getJSONObject(1);
                String desc2=obj2.getString("description");

                JSONObject obj3=offers.getJSONObject(2);
                String desc3=obj3.getString("description");
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    }

}
```

Now `String`  desc1,desc2,desc3 contains your 3 descriptions respectively. Do what ever you want with that `string`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still getting an error. Logcat says: 08-08 14:47:28.540: W/System.err(4872): org.json.JSONException: Value offers of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray